# Extjs4 Media Types

Tags: pdf, window, extjs4, media

How to display a PDF document in the Extjs4 window. When click on some link like

> OPEN DOCUMENT

```
  buttons: [{
            text :'OPEN DOCUMENT',
            formBind : true,
            handler:function()
          {}
```

Im trying to display pdf file. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to convert it to an image server-side, you can show it in an iframe:

```
buttons: [{
    text :'OPEN DOCUMENT',
    formBind : true,
    handler:function() {
        new Ext.window.Window({
            title: 'Document',
            height: 800,
            width: 800,
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [{
                html: '<iframe src="..."></iframe>'
            }]
        });
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

See example here: http://whatisextjs.com/extjs-4-tutorial/extjs-4-download-file-button

There are some undocumented properties that let you do what you want, with a button.  You can't handle a javascript event and download a file that way - most browsers will barf, for security reasons.